# Aircraft in lightning

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-limitations

What happens when an aircraft is hit by lightning? (Assuming that none of the engines is hit). Is there some FAA regulation (or some other regulation) which makes it mandatory for aircraft manufacturers to ensure that minimum damage occurs to the aircraft when it's struck by lightning?